# using conditionalPanel in Shiny ui.R and server.R: different selectInput based on a condition

Tags: r, shiny

I have looked at the majority of the stackoverflow posts on using conditionalPanel in shiny and still have not been able to find my bug.

I seem to be able to pass my parameters for "yr1" and "scen1" from server.R to ui.R, but the conditionalPanel does not appear to be working.

In my shiny app I have two selections to be made. Depending on the first selection, a different second set of selections should be displayed.  Below is the code I am currently testing:

```
library(shiny)
library(httpuv)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Global Temperature"),

  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("scen1", label = h3("Select 1 Map #1 Scenario"), 
                       choices = list("pre-2000" = "past", "post-2000: 850 ppm by 2100 (a2)"="a2","post-2000: 550 ppm by 2100 (b1)"="b1"), selected = "past"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'past'",
                     selectInput("yearspred1", "Select Map #1 Years Hindcasted",choices = c("1920-1939", "1940-1959", "1960-1979", "1980-1999"), selected="1920-1939", multiple=FALSE)),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'a2'",
                     selectInput("yearspred1", "Select Map #1 Years Predicted",choices = c("2020-2039", "2040-2059","2060-2079", "2080-2099")), selected="2020-2039", multiple=FALSE),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'b1'", 
                     selectInput("yearspred1", "Select Map #1 Years Predicted",choices = c("2020-2039", "2040-2059", "2060-2079", "2080-2099"), selected="2020-2039", multiple=FALSE)),
    ),
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("add1")),
    imageOutput("plot1")
  )  

 )
)
```

(I do the above for two selections but just show one here)

Server.R (you would need to fill in the path for the kml options to run this):

```
library(shiny)
library(httpuv)
library(rWBclimate)
library(ggplot2)

# get temperature data for ensembles
st=1900
en=2100
world <- c("USA")
options(kmlpath\="/Users/n....")
world_map_df <- create_map_df(world)
world_dat <- get_ensemble_temp(world, "annualavg", start=st, end=en)
world_dat$data <- as.numeric(as.character(world_dat$data))
world_dat<-subset(world_dat,world_dat$percentile==50) #subset to median percentile
world_dat$years=paste(world_dat$fromYear,world_dat$toYear, sep="-")
world_dat<-subset(world_dat, select=-c(percentile, fromYear, toYear))

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  scenario1<-reactive({input$scen1})
  yr1<-reactive({
    switch(input$yearspred1,  
           "1920-1939" = "1920-1939",
           "1940-1959" = "1940-1959",
           "1960-1979" = "1960-1979",
           "1980-1999" = "1980-1999",
           "2020-2039" = "2020-2039",
           "2040-2059" = "2040-2059",
           "2060-2079" = "2060-2079",
           "2080-2099" = "2080-2099")
  })

  dfyr1<-reactive({subset(world_dat, world_dat$scenario==scenario1())})
  df1<-reactive({subset(dfyr1(), dfyr1()$years==yr1())})
  output$add1 <- renderText({paste("Temperature prediction for years ", yr1(), " and ", scenario1(), " scenario") })

  output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    climate_map(world_map_df,df1(),return_map = T) + scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 34), low="blue", mid="white", high = "red", space="rgb", guide="colourbar") 
  })
})
```

Parameters are being passed, but the dropdown menu for "yr1" does not comply with the conditionalPanel conditions. I suspect it is in this part of the code, but I am not sure:

```
  yr1<-reactive({
    switch(input$yearspred1,  
           "1920-1939" = "1920-1939",
           "1940-1959" = "1940-1959",
           "1960-1979" = "1960-1979",
           "1980-1999" = "1980-1999",
           "2020-2039" = "2020-2039",
           "2040-2059" = "2040-2059",
           "2060-2079" = "2060-2079",
           "2080-2099" = "2080-2099")
  })
```

I tried replacing it with the following line:

```
yr1<-reactive({input$yearspred1})
```

But this did not fix the problem either.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What is the exact problem you are encountering?  'The code doesn't appear to be working' is extremely vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see the temptation to use the same ID for each `selectInput` within the `conditionPanel` but generally you shouldn't.  It is best to have clearly defined input ID's.  Additionally,  your `switch` statement is completely unnecessary like that where it just returns the exact same value that is put in.  After changing the `selectInput` ID's it is makes much more sense to have a switch statement.  You also have too many unnecessary `reactive` statements.  Unless you plan on using those statements in other functions throughout your server.R file, there is not point to have them there and they should just be combined wherever they are to be used (i.e. the `renderPlot` statement).  This is why the `yr` is made reactive because it will be used in `renderText` and `renderPlot`.  The following code works appropriately.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(httpuv)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Global Temperature"),

  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("scen1", label = h3("Select 1 Map #1 Scenario"), 
                       choices = list("pre-2000" = "past", "post-2000: 850 ppm by 2100 (a2)"="a2","post-2000: 550 ppm by 2100 (b1)"="b1"), selected = "past"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'past'",
                     selectInput("yearspred1", "Select Map #1 Years Hindcasted",choices = c("1920-1939", "1940-1959", "1960-1979", "1980-1999"), selected="1920-1939", multiple=FALSE)),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'a2'",
                     selectInput("yearspred2", "Select Map #1 Years Predicted",choices = c("2020-2039", "2040-2059","2060-2079", "2080-2099")), selected="2020-2039", multiple=FALSE),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.scen1 == 'b1'", 
                     selectInput("yearspred3", "Select Map #1 Years Predicted",choices = c("2020-2039", "2040-2059", "2060-2079", "2080-2099"), selected="2020-2039", multiple=FALSE))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("add1")),
    imageOutput("plot1")
  )  
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(httpuv)
library(rWBclimate)
library(ggplot2)

# get temperature data for ensembles
st=1900
en=2100
world <- c("USA")
options(kmlpath="/Users/n...")
world_map_df <- create_map_df(world)
world_dat <- get_ensemble_temp(world, "annualavg", start=st, end=en)
world_dat$data <- as.numeric(as.character(world_dat$data))
world_dat<-subset(world_dat,world_dat$percentile==50) #subset to median percentile
world_dat$years=paste(world_dat$fromYear,world_dat$toYear, sep="-")
world_dat<-subset(world_dat, select=-c(percentile, fromYear, toYear))

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  yr <- reactive({switch(
    input$scen1,
    "past" = input$yearspred1,
    "a2" = input$yearspred2,
    "b1" = input$yearspred3
  )})

  output$add1 <- renderText({paste("Temperature prediction for years ", yr(), " and ", input$scen1, " scenario") })

  output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    dfyr1<-subset(world_dat, world_dat$scenario==input$scen1)
    df1 <- subset(dfyr1, dfyr1$years==yr())
    climate_map(map_df=world_map_df,data_df=df1,return_map = T) + scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 34), low="blue", mid="white", high = "red", space="rgb", guide="colourbar") 
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much @cdeterman.  I am new to shiny and this streamlining of the code is helpful, but has also left me a little confused.   The code is getting close to doing what I would like it to; the issue I am having now is that the choices for (for example)  "input$yearspred1" do not show up in the dropdown menu. Although selectInput lists multiple choices, only the first choice is available.

Comment: One more thought @cdeterman:  the dropdown menu for the code actually works when deployed  on [shinyapps.io](http://nicolegoebel.shinyapps.io/tempPredict_oneplot). However the hardcoded options for the kml caching is now an issue, as the figure cannot be plotted (even though deployment was successful and complete).  I suspect it has to do with the external kml files needed to create the plot. These are usually stored in the same directory as the .R files according to a hard-coded path.  In order to deploy, do you know where do these files go what the options path should be?

Comment: @NicoleGoebel, couldn't you just set it to whatever the current directory would be with `getwd()`?

Comment: I just realized that if I run it locally, it all works!

Comment: However now I am trying to add a second sidebarPanel and back to the debugging process....

Comment: @NicoleGoebel, I suggest you open a new question with your most recent code as this is an independent question.  I (or another) may be able to better help you.  If my answer to your first question is satisfactory, please accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - accepted (and all solved)!