# Using linked selectInput functions in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

New to Shiny and can't seem to find this inforamtion yet: I am making an app with two `selectInput` drop-downs such that the second (highlighted in yellow) is dependant on the first.

[image]

This is for data exploration and basically goes through different folder contents. Here's what I would like to have:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "site", label = "Select Site", choices = dir(basepath)),
  selectInput(inputId = "duct", label = "Select Duct", 
              choices = dir(grep(input$site, dir(basepath, full.names = T), val = T)))
)
```

The above code does not work, clearly. I am not sure how to use `input$site` in another input function.

I found some answers: [Displaying multiple inputbox on selecting multiple variables using selectinput function in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063965/displaying-multiple-inputbox-on-selecting-multiple-variables-using-selectinput-f) and [using conditionalPanel in Shiny ui.R and server.R: different selectInput based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430253/using-conditionalpanel-in-shiny-ui-r-and-server-r-different-selectinput-based-o) but they are not directly applicable since I don't have an exhaustive list of possible options for the first input (`inputId = "site"`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a small example based on the `mtcars` dataset. Here you will find that the gears from the `selectInput` `site` will subset the data of and will return the second `selectInput` called `duct` which only displays the selected values from the first one:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  headerPanel("Test Shiny App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "site", label = "Select Site", choices = unique(mtcars$gear)),
    uiOutput("dynamicui")),
  mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dynamicui <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "duct", label = "Select Duct", choices = rownames(mtcars)[mtcars$gear %in% input$site])
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. I am new to this and I feel I don't have the "complete picutre" for Shiny inputs/outputs/layout options. I'm following the official webinars etc but is there another source to get an top level overview?

Comment: Make sure you do the tutorials on their website https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: Yes, those are the ones.